# How to format date in javascript returned from ajax request to c# web api?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html

I am making a GET request to a web api on a different server to get a C# DateTime object. I want its formatting to stay in the C# format like:

```
6/11/2014 6:46:43 PM
```

However, the formatting gets changed once I retrieve it in my javascript function like this:

```
2014-06-11T18:46:43.2730485Z
```

How do I preserve the formatting, or how do I convert it back to the original format?

Comment: There's no "C# format" - what you're seeing is the default format for your particular `CultureInfo`. Note that a `DateTime` value doesn't *have* a format - it just depends on how you render it. Now, I'd *strongly* recommend that for machine-to-machine communication, you use the ISO-8601 format from your second example. It's the most common standard for date/time serialization, and it doesn't have culture implications. (Your date looks like November 6th to me, as a UK person...)

Comment: Alright. Btw though, I managed to fixed the issue sending the datetime as a string. Either ways, I'll take your advice and try to work with the ISO-8601 format

Comment: related:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object, and then build a string from it.

```
var d = new Date(returnedDate);

var month = d.getMonth() + 1, // month indexed from 0-11
    day = d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear(),   // use instead of getYear() for 4-digit year
    hour = d.getHours(),
    minute = d.getMinutes(),
    second = d.getSeconds();

// Convert to 12-hour time, if that's your thing
if (hour >= 12) {
    hour -= 12;
    var meridiem = 'AM';
    // Correct for midnight
    if (hour === 0) hour = 12;
} else {
    var meridiem = 'PM';
}

var dStr = month + '/' + day + '/' + year + ' ' +
           hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second + ' ' + meridiem;
```

I'm unfamiliar with C#'s conventions for dates, but that looks pretty close to what you want. Note that this will interpret the time in the local timezone. Normalizing that mostly requires using the UTC methods for the Date object.

Being real here: JavaScript's date libraries are... lacking. I really do recommend using a library for this. I like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) a lot. Read up on [parsing a date string](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) and [formatting a date for display](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).